# How to write "Autocomplete" pure Javascript for JSON with no libraries?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, localhost, local-files

I'm new to Javascript and I have a Javascript web app on a local network that fetches data from a local JSON file.

I need to have the text search box loads autocomplete from the JSON file.

Is it possible to be done just in javascript with no jQuery, external libraries or XML requests?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible - after all, the libraries do it. Most are open source, and you might want to look at one or two of 'em to see how it's done.

Comment: First - think how you can do it on your own! Then go through the code of already implemented autocomplete plugin.